# How do you access nested elements of a hash with a single string key?

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm fooling around with Ruby and basically I have

```
@trans = { :links => {
    :quick_notes => "aaaaaaa"
  }
}
```

I want to call something like

```
def t
  #...something
end
t('links.quick_notes')
```

to access

```
trans[:links][:quick_notes]
```

I'm basically trying to achieve  the same functionality like when using Internationalizations

```
I18n.t('something.other.foo')
```

sofar  I came up with this approach

```
 def t(key)
   a=''
   key.to_s.split('.').each{|key|  a+="[:#{key}]" } 
   #now a == "[:links][:quick_notes]"
   #but I cant figure out how can I call it on  @trans variable

 end

 t('links.quick_notes')
```

Any ideas ? thanx

Comment: This is a fun exercise in recursion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get there with [`inject`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001494):

```
def t(key)
    key.to_s.split('.').inject(@trans) { |h, k| h[k.to_sym] }
end
```

Error checking and "no such entry" checking is left as an exercise.

Comment: Even cuter: `key.to_s.split('.').map(&:to_sym).inject(@trans, :[])`

Comment: @Marc-André: That is an interesting take on it. My block version draws my eyes to the important bit and makes it easy to "grok at a glance" for me though. Mostly a matter of preference and what you're used to though.

Comment: @mu & @pst: It's cute, but I completely agree it's not completely intuitive :-)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong... For @Marc-AndréLafortune's solution works in general, we have to assure that hash is `HashWithIndifferentAccess`

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo We're both assuming that the hash has symbol keys.

Comment: We're not assuming, that's clear from the question. Notice the call to `to_sym`.

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune: Yes the question implicitly states that the keys are symbols, our solutions are also assuming that the keys are symbols.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, here is some manky code that shows the [use of recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29).

```
def getKeyChain (obj, parts)
  if !obj || parts.size == 0
    # this is the base case
    obj
  else
    # this is the recursive case
    key = parts[0]
    if key.match(/^:/)
      key = key[1..key.size].to_sym
    end
    # each time recursing, pass a new state.
    # in this case, the value for the "key" and the remaining parts
    # that need resolving
    getKeyChain(obj[key], parts[1..parts.size])
  end
end

def getCompoundKey (obj, compound)
  # helper makes it easier to call while not making the
  # recursive function more complex.
  getKeyChain(obj, compound.split("."))
end

h0 = {:x => "hello"}
h1 = {"a" => {:b => "world"}}
puts getCompoundKey(h0, ":x")   # => hello
puts getCompoundKey(h1, "a.:b") # => world
```

Many improvements can be made... "use at own peril".

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something that interpolates `%{variable}`, including Array support, I've been using this:

```
def interpolate(string, hash)
  string.gsub(/%\{([^\}]*)\}/).each { |match| match[/^%{(.*)}$/, 1].split('.').inject(hash) { |h, k| h[(k.to_s == k.to_i.to_s) ? k.to_i : k.to_sym] } }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Ruby 2.3 Hash has a `dig` method.  "no such entry" checking is built in: if any of the keys is missing, then the whole expression returns `nil`. Usage:

```
@trans = { :links => {
    :quick_notes => "aaaaaaa"
  }
}

def t (str)
  syms = str.split(".").map(&:to_sym)
  @trans.dig(*syms)
end
p t('links.quick_notes')  # => "aaaaaaa"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another addition - If you have json or a hash that includes arrays as well as hashes - maybe something like this:

```
@trans = { :links => [ {
    :quick_notes => "aaaaaaa"
  },
  {
    :quick_notes => "bbbbbbb"
  } ],
  :page => 1
}
```

You can include a test of position in an array, you can do this sort of thing.

```
def t(key)
  key.split('.').inject(@trans) { |h,v| h.send('[]',v.to_i.to_s.eql?(v) ? v.to_i : v) }
end
```

This would allow you to pass a key like this

```
t('links.1.quick_notes')
```

and get the answer 'bbbbbb'