# How do i reduce the following code to one line in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How do i reduce the following code to one line in ruby?

```
unless(data["location"].nil?)
  unless(data["location"]["country"].nil?)
    unless(data["location"]["country"]["code"].nil?)
      #some codes
    end
  end  
end
```

Comment: This may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672007/how-do-you-access-nested-elements-of-a-hash-with-a-single-string-key/6672263#6672263 (my answer shows how it can be a more general approach that handles early end-cases).

Comment: And for your next challenge, try reducing the characters instead of the lines :) I got to:  "data.do_what_I_want"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [try](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) method, this method supported from Rails 2.3 and has a native support from Ruby 1.9.

```
if data.try(:[],'location').try(:[],'country').try(:[],'code')
 ...
end
```

Answer (score 10):

`if data["location"] && data["location"]["country"] && data["location"]["country"]["code]`

Ruby's `&&` operator is a short circut operator, so if the first operand is false, it will stop processing the rest of the condition. In addition. Any object that is not `nil`, is (for boolean purposes) `true`, so if the key exists, then it is `true`

Comment: The point being that the `&&` operator "short-circuits", so the second part is only evaluated if the first part is true, and so on. +1

Comment: @james..will `and` operator also work in the same manner? apart from having higher precedence, does `&&` have any other advantage over `and`

Comment: precendence is the only difference that i can think of. `and` short circuts as well, and to be honest, if you aren't worried about precedence, `and` is more readable

Answer (score 1):

There is always the good old ...

```
 if (data["location"]
     and data["location"]["country"] 
     and data["location"]["country"]["code"]) 
     # some code
 end
```

Comment: Well just remove the line breaks them ;) ... Now I understand the problem is how do this with less code. Unfortunately there is no built-in 'elvis' operator in Ruby (as in Groovy, If I'm not mistaken, where you can do seomthing like data?.location?.country?.code )

Comment: I was just kidding. It's basically the same answer as James Deville's, which is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can bring out the big guns and use [the `andand` gem](http://andand.rubyforge.org/). It's not a production suggestion (or even terribly serious for real life), but is fascinating and directly addresses your need. 
With `andand` you can do

```
data['location'].andand['country'].andand['code']
```

You'll get a bonus warning about undefining `object_id` and how it may cause serious problems, but just smile and enjoy the metaprogramming :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is evil, but it's late for me….

```
class NilClass
  def [](args=""); self; end
end

if data["location"]["country"]["code"]
  # robot armies eat your pancakes
end
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer

```
!data["location"].nil? && !data["location"]["country"].nil? && !data["location"]["country"]["code"].nil? && #some codes
```

But why?

Comment: added an explanation in my answer. `if !foo.nil?` can be replaced `if foo` (just as an FYI)

Answer (score 0):

Add a method to your Hash class

```
class Hash

  def all_keys

     keys = []

     each_pair do |k1, v1|

     if v1.is_a?(Hash)

        v1.each_pair { |k2, v2|
           if !v2.is_a?(Hash) then keys << [k1, k2]; next end
        v2.each_pair { |k3, v3|
           if !v3.is_a?(Hash) then keys << [k1, k2, k3]; next end
        v3.each_pair { |k4, v4|
           if !v4.is_a?(Hash) then keys << [k1, k2, k3, k4]; next end
        v4.each_pair { |k5, v5|
           if !v5.is_a?(Hash) then keys << [k1, k2, k3, k4, k5]; next end
        v5.each_pair { |k6, v6|
           if !v6.is_a?(Hash) then keys << [k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, k6]; next end
           # add more v[n].each_pair ... loops to process more hash dimensions
        } } } } }      # "}" * 5

        else
           keys << [k1]
        end

     end

    keys

 end

end
```

Now, use this code to check if the nested key exists:

```
data.all_keys.first.include? "code"
```