# Ruby change value in hash by reference

Tags: ruby, reference

I'm using eval to work with a hash. This part works:

```
some_hash = {"a" => {"b" => "c"}}
target_hash = "some_hash"
target_key = "['a']"

my_value = eval(target_hash + target_key)
puts "my_value " + my_value.to_s
```

and prints:

```
my_value {"b"=>"c"}
```

How would I change the value, using eval, so that the hash results in this:

```
some_hash = {"a" => {"d" => "e"}}
```

Thanks

Edit:

I don't think I'm explaining correctly. I have to drill down into a hash, but I want the flexibility to do it with a string that is set at run time. That string could be `"['key_level_1']['key_level_2']['key_level_3']"` which is supposed to refer to `some_hash['key_level_1']['key_level_2']['key_level_3']`.

And again, i need to set that value to something. Does that make sense?

Comment: Consider *not* using evil-- err, eval here. There are numerous "clean ways" to approach this problem in the general case.

Comment: Ha, I knew someone would say that. Any hints?  pls see my comment below, thanks.

Comment: No, seriously, this is awful. There's no reason to use '["a"]' where "a" would do fine. You don't need to parameterize the _syntax_!

Answer (score 1):

I would take an array e.g. `['key1', 'key2', 'key3']` (which can be constructed from an appropriately formatted string) and the "root object" and use it to locate a particular "target object" branch (I would recommend recursion). Then manipulate the appropriate object that was located. In this case `some_hash` should be the "root object" to start the traversal from, and not a string.

Here is a link to a *really old* answer I wrote (when I still actively used ruby). It doesn't handle the assignment bit, but I believe it shows the start of a valid approach that is eval-free: [How do you access nested elements of a hash with a single string key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672007/how-do-you-access-nested-elements-of-a-hash-with-a-single-string-key/6672263#6672263) After the "target object" is located, then it's just a matter of assigning a new value to particular key. (The accepted answer in the linked post is also a gem, if not a little more cryptic and symbol-leaking.)

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Hash#replace`

```
def changeHash(a, b, targetHash, targetKey)
  change = ".replace({'#{a}' => '#{b}'})"
  my_value = eval(target_hash + target_key + change)
end

some_hash = {"a" => {"b" => "c"}}
target_key = "['a']"
changeHash('d', 'e', 'some_hash', '["a"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest setting up a method like this:

```
def hash_change(target_hash,target_key,*new_value)
     if new_value
          target_hash["target_key"] = new_value
     end
     puts "my_value " + target_hash["target_key"]
end
```

That will give you flexibility to either display the original or a new hash should you pass in a new value.

Edit: sorry forgot the call to the method

```
hash_change(some_hash,"a",{"d" => "e"})
```

Comment: I don't think I'm explaining correctly.  I have to drill down into a hash, but I want the flexibility to do it with a string that is set at run time.  That string could be "['key_level_1']['key_level_2']['key_level_3']" which is supposed to refer to some_hash['key_level_1']['key_level_2']['key_level_3'].  And again, i need to set that value to something.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah I am not following you. Do you have a more concrete example you could put in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, for the help. I changed it up a bit. Instead of passing in string as array, I just pass in an object like this:

```
{some_hash => {"a" => {"b" => "nil"}}}
```

Then I recursively traverse both the reference, and the real hash.  When I detect `nil` in the reference, I know I am there.